# Problem with \nocite{*} and \renewcaptionname after updating to KOMA-Script v3.32

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, miktex, koma-script

After having updated my MiKTeX installation from KOMA-script v3.31 to v3.32 I ran into a problem when using the `\nocite{*}` command from the `biblatex` package in conjunction with a `\renewcaptionname` from `KOMA-script`.

In my original document version the command `\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}` was before the line `\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}`. This worked well in the past up to and including KOMA-script version v3.31.

Compilation is done with the following command sequence:

```
pdflatex MWE
biber MWE
pdflatex MWE
pdflatex MWE
```

However after updating to KOMA-script v3.32 this failed with the following warnings during the last `pdflatex MWE` run.

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                MWE
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Moreover all references and citations are numbered with `[0]` and not `[1]-[6]`.
The bibliography only contains the actually cited references and not all six references as expected due to `\nocite{*}` being used.

I was able to work around this problem by moving the line `\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}` after `\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}` or to any place later in the preamble for example directly before `\begin{document}` as shown in the commented line of the MWE.

This arrangement of the preamble compiles with both versions of KOMA-script v3.31 and v3.32.

My questions are:

Is this change of behavior intended in KOMA-script v3.32 or is this some unwanted glitch that slipped into v3.32?

What are the rules to specify things like `\figurename` using the documented KOMA-script way of doing so?

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% using this line:
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}
%
% only references Author1, Author2 and Author4 are included
% all references and citations are numbered with [0]
%
% LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
% Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
% (biblatex)                MWE
% (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{Bibliography.bib}
@book{Author1,
  author          = {A. Author1},
  title           = {Titel 1}
}
@book{Author2,
  author          = {B. Author2},
  title           = {Titel 2}
}
@book{Author3,
  author          = {C. Author3},
  title           = {Titel 3}
}
@book{Author4,
  author          = {D. Author4},
  title           = {Titel 4}
}
@book{Author5,
  author          = {E. Author5},
  title           = {Titel 5}
}
@book{Author6,
  author          = {F. Author6},
  title           = {Titel 6}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{BibCat_1}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{BibCat_2}

\addtocategory{BibCat_1}{Author1, Author2, Author3}
\addtocategory{BibCat_2}{Author4, Author5, Author6}

\nocite{*}

% using this line instead:
%\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}
%
% works as expected
% all 6 references are included and correctly numbered as [1] - [6]
% no warnings

\begin{document}

Zitate: \cite{Author1} \cite{Author4} \cite{Author2}

\appendix
\printbibheading

\printbibliography[
  heading=subbibliography,
  category=BibCat_1,
  title=BibCat 1]

\printbibliography[
  heading=subbibliography,
  category=BibCat_2,
  title=BibCat 2]

\end{document}
```

When using no bibliography categories, citations and references are not numbered with [0] but still `\nocite{*}` doesn't include uncited references into the bibliography.

Here is the second MWE without categories:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% using this line:
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}
%
% only references Author1, Author2 and Author4 are included
%
% LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
% Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
% (biblatex)                MWE
% (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{Bibliography.bib}
@book{Author1,
  author          = {A. Author1},
  title           = {Titel 1}
}
@book{Author2,
  author          = {B. Author2},
  title           = {Titel 2}
}
@book{Author3,
  author          = {C. Author3},
  title           = {Titel 3}
}
@book{Author4,
  author          = {D. Author4},
  title           = {Titel 4}
}
@book{Author5,
  author          = {E. Author5},
  title           = {Titel 5}
}
@book{Author6,
  author          = {F. Author6},
  title           = {Titel 6}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\nocite{*}

% using this line instead:
%\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}
%
% works as expected
% all 6 references are included and correctly numbered as [1] - [6]
% no warnings

\begin{document}

Zitate: \cite{Author1} \cite{Author4} \cite{Author2}

\appendix
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: it is clearly a bug, the command shouldn't eat citations, but it is not quite easy to see what happens (and where the bug is)

Comment: Ok, thanks
For the moment the workaround is ok for me.

Comment: actually I don't think the the renewcommand is the problem, I get zeros and warning also without it, it looks more like a problem with defernumbers.

Comment: Could you reproduce that everything works as expected if \renewcaptionname is moved after \usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex} ?

Comment: I also have a MWE without using bibliography categories.
In this case there are no zeros. But still not all six references are included, only the three acually cited.
I will update my post and include this second MWE also.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It appears to be an issue with `\AfterPreamble`. The following MWE shows a similar issue https://gist.github.com/moewew/b0a0dc52867060daeaf7186de496416f. The problem is that code from `\AfterPreamble` may be run before all code from `\AtBeginDocument` has been executed.

Comment: @moewe yes, I just found too that it is triggered by the \AtBeginDocument in the koma command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer We could probably use `\AfterEndPreamble` in `biblatex` to be on the safe side, but I'm wondering if I should report this at the `etoolbox` bug tracker. (If I understand correctly the problem comes down to the new hook system not allowing us to split the top level hooks. I'm wondering if this could cause counter intuitive results in other situations as well.)

Comment: I opened https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1066 to track this on the `biblatex` side.

Comment: @moewe I added a comment to the issue.

Comment: @BaWue as a work-around move the \nocite{*} behind \begin{document}, that should work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, thank you. I wasn't aware that this is allowed. But the biblatex docu actually tells so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with `biblatex`'s use of the new LaTeX hook system (at least until the release of LaTeX 2020-10-01 PL3). The new LaTeX hooks would no longer guarantee that `\AtBeginDocument`/`\AfterPreamble` calls are executed in the exact order they appear in the code (cf. https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/441). `biblatex` relied on the previous behaviour where this was the case.

In patch level 3 of LaTeX 2020-10-01 there has been some effort to make `\AtBeginDocument` calls more reliable in terms of ordering and separately `biblatex` addressed the issue in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1066.

The issue should definitely be resolved in `biblatex` v3.16 (released 2020-12-31), but it may also be resolved with an update to LaTeX 2020-10-01 PL3 (released 2020-12-31).

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) [mentions in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567911/problem-with-nocite-and-renewcaptionname-after-updating-to-koma-script-v3-3#comment1431786_567911): A workaround would have been to move `\nocite{*}` into the document body. But this workaround is no longer required if you update your TeX system.